# I can't run TypeScript inside "node:bookworm" docker image

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose

When I tried to run TypeScript server inside a container from "node:21.1.0-bookworm" it didn't work and gave me this error :

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /app/src/index.ts
```

I tried to install it manually by running "npm install -g typescript" in Dockerfile and by "docker exec -it"  it didn't work!

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:21.1.0-bookworm as test-node-image
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
ARG NODE_ENV
RUN npm install -g typescript
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /app
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD [ "npm","run","start" ]
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsx": "^4.4.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.2"
  },
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsx watch src/index.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },

  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"
  },
  "watchOptions": {
    "watchFile": "dynamicPriorityPolling",
    "watchDirectory": "dynamicPriorityPolling",
    "excludeDirectories": ["**/node_modules", "dist"]
  }
}
```

Note: The same project works on "node:18" without any problems!

Comment: have you tried `21.2.0-bookworm`?

Comment: did you try `node:20`? or even `node:21` (which would be the same as `21.2.0-bookworm` mentioned above)

Comment: Works to 19. . 20 and above didn't work. I don't know how to add TypeScript manually!?

Comment: `npm install -g typescript` would be doing it ... the issue is the unknown file extension `.ts` error ... which would be odd for `tsx` to produce

Comment: I added it to the Dockerfile as shown above, and I also added it to “devDependencies” and downloaded it from “docker exec -it” .. it didnt work. It still gives me the same error!

Comment: oh, so it's `npm install -g typescript` that throws the error?

Comment: or is it the `npm install` that results in the error?

Answer (score 1):

I exactly had the same problem just now and I managed to fix it by switching from `ts-node` to `tsx` but seems like you're already using `tsx`.

But you can try referring to my `tsconfig.json`'s changes.

Try changing:

`"module": "NodeNext"`

`"moduleResolution": "NodeNext"`

Comment: Yes right. I was using nodemon and it didn't work. Maybe I didn't rebuild the container to work with tsx. I have rebuilt it now, tsx works well, nondemone does not work, but there is a problem that it does not restart the server with the updates. "watchOptions" doesn't work with it as it does with nodemon. How do I solve this problem?